# Animating SVG resizing through CSS

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

I am not sure if the title justifies my problem.

I am trying to animate a svg and the css portion is following

```
.side {
      animation: a1 3s 1s linear forwards;
      transform-origin: center bottom;
    }         

@keyframes a1 {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1,0);
      }

      100% {
        transform: scale(1, 1); 
      }
```

The svg portion is following

```
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="582" height="554" viewBox="0 0 582 554">
  <g>
<rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="581" height="553" fill="#fff" stroke="black"/>

  </g>
 <rect class="box" x="257" y="58" width="204" height="294" fill="#fff" stroke="red" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
<rect class="side" x="125" y="58" width="14" height="464" fill="blue" stroke="blue" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</svg>
```

What I am actually trying to achieve with the animation is the blue side bar (svg class = "side") to perform all the steps of keyframe a1 and at the end to align with the box.

For example, start from
[image: start]

then 
perform all the keyframmes of a1

and end as
[image: end]

I am struggling with this and don't know how to do that. If someone can please help would be great. I prefer to do this by using CSS.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 0% {
       height:464px;
      }      100% {
        height:294px
      }

Comment: @ariel many thanks. It worked. If you want to put this as an answer. I will accept it.